# Mercurial convert extension not able to pull from remote Git repository

Tags: git, mercurial, mercurial-convert

I'm trying to do a '`hg convert`', to pull from a Git repo into an Hg one.

Now, I don't have Git installed on my Windows 7 machine; is that necessary? I'm using the TortoiseHG commandline, and I have activated the convert extension ('`hg help convert`' works fine).

Here's an example of the command I'm trying to use:

```
hg convert -s git -d hg https://github.com/mysticbob/glm.git gittest
```

That's a public repo on Github, so I should be able to convert from it. And the address is what Github says one should use for getting. What I get is the following message:

```
initializing destination gittest repository
https://github.com/mysticbob/glm.git does not look like a Git repository
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I believe [issue 1246](https://bz.mercurial-scm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1246), you need to have git installed for the [`hg convert`](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ConvertExtension#Converting_to_Mercurial) extension to work.

Even with Git installed, you might experience some other issues with the import, in which case you could consider other alternatives such as:

- converting the git repo to a svn one, and then importing that svn repo into a mercurial one
- or trying the [`hg-git`](http://hg-git.github.com/) mercurial plugin, which specifically mentions:

> This plugin is implemented entirely in Python - there are no Git binary dependencies, you do not need to have Git installed on your system.

(But I don't know if `hg-git` works with recent 1.7+ Mercurial versions)